# applying command on multiple columns of each element of a list

Tags: r

I have a list with 16 elements all having the same variables (31 columns). Now i want to make a few changes on this variables and hope that I can do them for each element of the list. Simplified the list looks like this

```
>list
>$`M2_2004` 
>       A      B      C 
>1      2      1      3 
>2      4      6      5 
>3      6      4      0 
... 

>$`M2_2005` 
>      A       B      C 
>70    5       9      1 
>71    4       6      5 
>72    2       5      8 
...
```

For example, now i want to add 2 leading numbers to the columns B and C for each element of the list. This works with the following command

```
sprintf("%04d", B)
```

where B is the column. Since I am quite new to R, I would apply this to each column of each element with a seperate line of code, but i hope to speed up the process by doing this in a single command.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lapply` to apply the same function to each element of a list, and `sapply` to apply the same function to multiple columns of the same data frame:

```r
lapply(your_list, function(x){
  x[c("B", "C")] <- sapply(x[c("B", "C")], function(y) sprintf("%04d", y))
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I've tried your suggesting an recieve the following error message: 
`Error in `[.data.table`(x, c("B", "C")) : When i is a data.table (or character vector), the columns to join by must be specified using 'on=' argument (see ?data.table), by keying x (i.e. sorted, and, marked as sorted, see ?setkey), or by sharing column names between x and i (i.e., a natural join). Keyed joins might have further speed benefits on very large data due to x being sorted in RAM.`